# how to sort the documents according to an field in lucene?

Tags: sorting, lucene, document

guys.

I've got billions of records which have two attributes:

> RecordCreatedTime, RecordContent

I've used lucene to index the records, and it is done.

Now I want to query some records according to the `RecordCreatedTime`, for example, check out the document just in November, 2013.

I am considering to sort the documents with `RecordCreatedTime`, and have tried some methods like `NumericDocValuesSorter` but it didn't work.
Can you guys provide some more materials so I can take a careful look??
Much thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out Lucene's [`DateTools`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html) which provides you with the tools to represent dates in a way that is appropriate for searching and sorting in the index.  A [`TermRangeQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermRangeQuery.html) can be used to search a particular range (such as the month of November, 2013), when indexed in that format.

You can also sort easily, by passing a [`Sort`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) into your search call.

For example, something like:

```
String startDateString = DateTools.dateToString(startDate, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);
String endDateString = DateTools.dateToString(endDate, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);
TermRangeQuery query = TermRangeQuery.newStringRange("recordCreatedTime", startDateString, endDateString, true, false);
SortField field = new SortField('recordCreatedTime', SortField.Type.STRING);
Sort sort = new Sort(field);
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, numDocs, sort);
```

Comment: Thanks. Currently I convert time granularity into a month (use string to store) to speed up my queryies, it seems it is quite similar to the way used in DateTools.